# JDK installing problems

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I install the windowBuilder for working GUI in eclipse neon and after finishing the installation I restart my eclipse, IT show this error what should I do??
[image]

Comment: Please do not post links to error messages.  They should be included directly in the question.

Comment: I am sorry I am new In here

Comment: If you know just answer my question please

Comment: Eclipse Neon requires Java **8**. 7 will not do. Install *how*? How have you tried to solve this so far?

Answer (score 1):

on second look, your JDK path isnt correct, your are using jaavaw.exe, that isnt right.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have no JVM in the specified path. Ensure it actually exists and you have rights to access it. Ensure also that JVM is the same architecture as your Eclipse (either 32 or 64 bits).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the correct path of javaw.exe in eclipse.ini.
Look for the following.

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javaw.exe
```

eclipse.ini file is located on the same folder where your eclipse.exe is located.